# Need help in resolving Excel VBA compiling error

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I keep getting a `Compile error: Argument not optional` in my VBA excel code when I want to store value by calling a function. The main purpose of the function is to record values in a dictionary based on certain conditions used. However, I get the error above and can't find a solution because it looks like I have supplied arguments to every function component that requires it.

```
Function landed_cost_calc(statename As String, powersource As String) As Single

Dim charges_data As New Scripting.Dictionary

'Find relevant data to be used
charges_data = finddata(statename, powersource) <--- compile error
```

The function that is being called `finddata` finds relevant data based on statename and powersource. Snippet of code is mentioned below:

```
Function finddata(statename As String, powersource As String) As Dictionary

'1. declare variables
Dim statename As String
Dim powersource As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim var As New Scripting.Dictionary
Set var = New Dictionary
'declare charges variables
Dim tariff As Single
Dim CTU_charges_unit As Single

'2. find records that match the criteria and use them
'Assign value to variable
finalrow = Sheets("Charges Data").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

'Loop through Charges Data to find relevant numbers
For i = 3 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 2) = statename Then
        If powersource = "Solar" Then
            If Cells(i, 3) = "Tariff" Then
                tariff = Cells(i, 5).Value
                var.Add "tariff", tariff
            ElseIf Cells(i, 3) = "CTU charges" Then
                CTU_charges_unit = Cells(i, 5).Value
                var.Add "CTU_charges_unit", CTU_charges_unit
                End If
            End If
        End If
Next i
'Return data
finddata = var
End Function
```

Further, statename and powersource is being sourced from the parent function (which is the first procedure that is run) with snippet below:

```
Sub landed_cost()

'Declare variables
Dim statename As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
'Declare calculation variables
Dim solar_landed_cost As Single
Dim overall_landed_cost As Single
'Declare energy share variables
Dim solar_share As Single

'Assign Share value
solar_share = Sheets("Snapshot").Cells(5, 5).Value

'Assign value to variable
lastrow = Sheets("Snapshot").Range("M8").Row

'Loop through relevant rows for calculation
For j = 4 To lastrow
    statename = Cells(j, 13).Value
        
        'Calculate landed cost for each power source
        solar_landed_cost = landed_cost_calc(statename, "Solar")
        
        'Overall landed cost
        overall_landed_cost = (solar_share * solar_landed_cost)
        
        'Change the value of each customer
        Cells(j, 15).Value = overall_landed_cost
        
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Just as a heads up, you probably don't want to declare **statename** and **powersource** again  within **finddata**.

Comment: In addition to the above, the function returns a dictionary (object) so you must set its value using the `Set` keyword. `Set charges_data = finddata(...)` The same applies to the rest of your code.

Comment: @KostasK. I am a novice to VBA. could you please provide me with a reference doc for when to add `Set` keyword? Thanks

Comment: It's quite simple, when the variable is an object you need to use `Set`. See this and familiarize yourself with the various data types (there's a link on the bottom of the page). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement